# How to escape spaces in grep search results? (filenames)

Tags: linux, shell, grep, search

When I run this:

```
for f in $(grep -r --include=*.directory "search-string"); do echo $f; done;
```

I get the search results split up by the spaces in the search results' filenames.

How can I escape the spaces in the grep search results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the list of files in an array and are using the bash shell (version 4.4 or above), you'd do:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  grep -rlZ --include='*.directory' "search-string" .
)
```

With the `zsh` shell:

```
files=(${(0)"$(grep -rlZ --include='*.directory' "search-string" .)"})
```

And loop over them with:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

With `zsh`, you can skip the intermediary array with:

```
for file in ${(0)"$(grep -rlZ --include='*.directory' "search-string" .)"}; do
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
}
```

Beware that leaving a word expansion unquoted (like `$f` or `$(...)`) has a very special meaning in `bash`, generally not the one you want, and file names can contain any byte value other than `0`, so `0` aka NUL is the only delimiter than can safely be used when expressing a list of file paths as a stream of byte with delimiter. That's what the `-Z`/`--null` option of GNU `grep` is for.

With simple shells like `dash`, you could have `gawk` for instance take the output of GNU `grep` to generate a list of shell-quoted file names for `sh` to evaluate as shell code:

```
eval set -- "$(
  grep -rlZ --include='*.directory' "search-string" . |
    gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS=' ' -v q="'" '
      {gsub(q, q "\\" q q); print q $0 q}'
)"

for file do
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

If you can guarantee your file names won't contain newline characters, you can simplify it to:

```
IFS='
'
set -o noglob

for file in $(grep -rl --include='*.directory' "search-string" .); do
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

You can skip the `set -o noglob` if you can guarantee the file names also don't contain `*`, `?`, `[` (and possibly `\`, and more glob operators depending on the shell and shell version).

Comment: Still testing this but it says "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" with the bash shell on Debian10.

Comment: That's likely  not the `bash` shell, more likely `dash`. The `bash` shell would complain on that code if it was invoked as `sh` (in which case it stops supporting `<(...)` process substitution), but it would then give a differently worded error message. I've added an approach for `dash`.

Comment: And do you have a `*.directory` file that contains `search-string`?

Comment: Don't we really already have this question answered somewhere so we could just link to it / point a duplicate?

Comment: @ilkkachu, probably. It's similar to [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: You could link it if you find it, I didn't which indicates that it's not well-findable. It's a common task that's supposed to be simple so I would have expected there to be easily findable information on it.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm, I'm definitely not blaming you for not finding one. A number of posts here are useful in general, and can perhaps work as tutorials, but are hard to find among everything else. The only sort of table of contents is the tag wikis, and I'm not sure if any new users know how to find them. It's just that I thought I've seen a couple of answers quite similar to this a few times already.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure there are no newlines in the file paths then you can limit word splitting to newline:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(grep -r --include=*.directory "search-string"); do
    echo "$f"
done
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Comment: It also assumes file names don't contain wildcard characters (you need `set -o noglob` when using split+glob and wanting only split), that's there's no file whose name starts with `--include` and ends in `.directory` in the currently directory (that `*` should be quoted), and that file names don't contain backslash and are not combinations of the options supported by `echo` (`echo` can't be used for arbitrary data).

Comment: Beware that `IFS="$oldIFS"` doesn't restore `IFS` correctly if it was initially unset.

Comment: Thanks but this splits for every "n" character. The output is correct when removing the \n in single quotes but it only has one result in the for loop so it only echoes one string.

Comment: This worked well when modified as in Stéphane Chazelas' answer (see code at bottom).

Answer (score 1):

The GNU guys really messed up when they gave `grep` options for finding files. Hopefully they don't plan to give that same capability to sed, awk, cat, tr, wc, and every other UNIX tool and hopefully they don't plan to give grep options to do other things that existing tools do like sort files, replace strings, translate characters, count characters, etc. There's a perfectly good UNIX tool to **find** files and it has a pretty obvious name - `find`.

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(find . -name '*.directory' -exec grep -lZ 'search-string' {} +)
```

The above requires GNU tools (which you're already using) to use NUL-terminated input/output. If you don't have newlines in your file names then you can just use standard tools instead.